# Magento 1.x Date field is not getting updated when we use setData method with multiple setData

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

We are using Magento 1.9 for our application. Here is my sample code

```
 $customer_collection= Mage::getModel("customer/customer")->load($data['customer_id']);
 foreach ($data['data'] as $key => $customer) {
    $customer_collection->setData($customer['attribute_name'] , $customer['attribute_value']); 
 }
$customer_collection->save(); //finally saving the data
```

Above code is working for all the fields except date field. Issue is when we send multiple data including date fields, other fields are getting updated but date field is not getting updated. Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: is `date` custom attribute you just added?

Comment: Yes. Field name `score_stab_grad_date` .

Comment: Magento caches table structures even if cache is disabled. It's a good thing to "Flush Cache Storage" and thy again. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@mladen-ilić](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5714648/mladen-ili%C4%87) Suggested,

I did **Flush Cache Storage** and tried again to post the data. It works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

For date field update try to use

```
$object->setData($attributeCode, Varien_Date::now());
```

Comment: Have to add the date value which is coming from DB. Not the current time.

Comment: Data getting saved when I send the JSON data from postman. But through CURL request the same data is not getting updated.